# How to do filtering of multiple files in a directory using awk?

Tags: loops, awk, gawk

I am trying to filter multiple files in a directory based on a blacklist file
when I used a single line without loop the script works fine...

```
 awk >rest.txt 'NR==FNR{_[$1];next}!($1 in _)' FS=" " blist_file.txt main_file.txt
```

but when I add a loop, i get error, what could be wrong?

```
$ for f in main_file* do awk >res_$f 'NR==FNR{_[$1];next}!($1 in _)' FS=" " blist_file.txt $f; done
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `>
```

Comment: What does this do  `>rest.txt `?  I have never seen redirect like this within `awk`.  Normal use: `awk 'test {do something}' infile > outfile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a semi-colon. This:

```
for f in main_file* do
```

should syntactically be this:

```
for f in main_file*; do
```

but of course this is the wrong approach anyway - just call awk once:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {blist[$1]; next }
    FNR==1 {close(out); out="res_" FILENAME }
    !($1 in blist) { print > out }
' blist_file.txt main_file*.txt
```

You don't need to set FS to `" "` as that is the default value and wrt wherever you learned that using "_" as a variable name is a good idea - never use that source again!

Comment: I tested the script and it will generate an output file, if the output file is not empty. How could I generate an empty file even when there's no content in the output?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking for but I THINK what you want is to just add `printf "" > out` at the end of the FNR==1 block: `FNR==1 {close(out); out="res_" FILENAME; printf "" > out }`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the output I am looking for. Thanks for the pointer.