# Filtering using awk returns empty files

Tags: awk

I have a similar  problem to this question: [How to do filtering of multiple files in a directory using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125111/how-to-do-filtering-of-multiple-files-in-a-directory-using-awk)

The solution in the answers of the question above does not work for me.

I have tab-delimited txt files (all in folder Observation_by_pracid). For each file, I want to create a new file that only contains rows with a specific value in column $9 (medcodeid). The specific values are to be found in medicalcode_list.txt.
There is no error, however it returns only empty files.

**Codelist**

```
medcodeid   
2576        
3199
```

**Format of input files**

```
patid           consid      ... medcodeid   
500470520002    3062539302  ... 2576    
951924020002    3062538414  ... 310803013       
503478020002    3061587464  ... 257619018       
951924020002    3062537807  ... 55627011        
503576720002    3062537720  ... 3199
```

**Desired output**

```
patid           consid      ... medcodeid       
500470520002    3062539302  ... 2576    
503576720002    3062537720  ... 3199
```

**My code**

```
mkdir HBA1C_observation_bypracid
awk '
    NR==FNR {mlist[$1]; next }
    FNR==1 {close(out); out="HBA1C_observation_bypracid/HBA1C_" FILENAME }
    ($9 in mlist) { print > out } 
' PATH/medicalcode_list.txt *.txt
```

**Solution**

```
mkdir HBA1C_observation_bypracid
awk '
    BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
    NR==FNR {mlist[$1]; next }
    FNR==1 {close(out); out="HBA1C_observation_bypracid/HBA1C_" FILENAME }
    ($9 in mlist) { print > out } 
' PATH/medicalcode_list.txt *.txt
```

Adding "BEGIN..." solved my problem.

Comment: No. I just need the most efficient way as lots of data will have to be processed.

Comment: If you replace $9 with $NF, what does that give?

Comment: You are most likely suffering from `CRLF` line endings in either `codelist` or your input files (but not both). This means that you try to match `2576\r` with `2576` and this will not work. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45772525/8344060) for more information. You can quickly check your files with `cat -vET file` to see if there is something unexpected there.

Comment: or easier: just type `file filename` this will give you the info

Comment: Both files are ASCI. The line endings are shown as ^I

Comment: Correction: Line endings were $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I think it would be simpler to loop over in the shell (understanding that this will reread the code list more than once), with a simpler awk function that you should be able to test and debug. Something like:

```sh
for file in *.txt; do
    awk 'FNR == NR { mlist[$1] } FNR != NR && ($9 in mlist) { print }' \
       PATH/medicalcode_list.txt "$file" > HBA1C_observation_bypracid/HBA1C_"$file"
done
```

You should be able to start without the redirection to make sure that for a single file, you get the results printed to the terminal that you were expected. If you don't there might be some incorrect assumption about the files.

Another option would be to write a separate awk script that writes the code to hard-code the list in another awk script. Also gives the advantage to check the contents of the variable `mlist`.

```sh
printf 'BEGIN {\n%s\n}\n $9 in mlist { print }' \
    "$(awk '{ print "mlist[" $1 "]" }' PATH/medicalcode_list.txt)" > filter.awk

for file in *.txt; do
   awk -f filter.awk "$file" > HBA1C_observation_bypracid/HBA1C_"$file"
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your ideas. Your first approach resulted in the same output I had had before: I got an empty output file. "The hard-coded list" looks like this: cat filter.awk 
BEGIN {
mlist[medcodeid]
mlist[2576]
mlist[3199]
}
However, the output of  awk -f filter.awk "$file" > HBA1C_observation_bypracid/HBA1C_"$file"  was an output file without header and with random lines from the source file, not the lines that should have been filtered

Comment: Based on this, it looks to me what you think is column 9 is not the same as what awk thinks. I'd start small and just use the simplest awk scripts to see what awk really thinks is in different columns. Starting with `awk '{ print $1 }'` and then $2, etc. You also commented that the line endings were `^I`. That would be strange, because that normally represents a tab character, which is also what you were saying was the delimiter. As the other commenter stated, you'll want to make sure you have unix line endings as well.

Comment: Thank you! This was an important hint. You were right - the input files were not recognized (the tab stops / empty cells were collapsed). Both, my codes and your code works perfectly if I add BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" } .

Answer (score 3):

You can join two files on a column using `join`.

- Files must be sorted on the joined column. To perform a numerical **`sort`** on a column, use sort this way, where `N` is the column number:

  ```
    sort -kN -n FILE
  ```
- You also need to get ride of the first line (column names) of each files. You can use tail command the way below, where N is the number of line from which you want to output the content (so 2nd line):

  ```
  tail -n +N
  ```
- ... But still need to display the column values:

  ```
  head -n 1 FILE
  ```
- To join two files f1 and f2, on the fields c1 of f1 and c2 of f2, and output fields y of files x:

  ```
  join -1 c1 -2 c2 f1 f2 -o "x.y, x.y"
  ```

Working sample:

```
head -n 1 input_file
for input_file in *.txt ; do
    join -1 1 -2 9 -o "2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7 2.8 2.9" \
         <(tail -n +2 PATH/medicalcode_list.txt | sort -k1 -n) \
         <(tail -n +2 "$input_file" | sort -k3 -n)
done
```

Result (for the input file you gave):

```
patid           consid      ... medcodeid   
500470520002 3062539302 ... 2576
503576720002 3062537720 ... 3199
```

---

**Note:** the column names arent aligned with the values. Don't know if it's a prerequisite. You can format the display with `printf` command.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas! This runs without error however there is neither any output file nor output in the console. What am I missing? I am also not sure where exactly the filtering happens in your code. I am just starting with awk

Comment: I still have not been able to get this running. However, I found a solution. I had to add BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }  to my code. Thank you very much for the effort!